# What is the sound power produced at a defined frequency by a woofer of given diameter and excursion?

Tags: acoustics, power

Assuming an infinitely rigid woofer of a given diameter and oscillating with a given excursion at a given frequency, what is the SPL (sound pressure level) at 1 m distance?

I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_power#Mathematical_definition linking sound power to diameter, but I cannot find how to introduce excursion and frequency in that formula.

Since reflex systems may produce constructive interference, the question is related to a speaker in a closed enclosure, or (that I think it's the same) to a speaker mounted in an infinite wall.

Comment: First of all, be careful!  Sound Power Level, $L_w$ is a property of a source.  Sound Pressure Level, $L_p$ on the other hand, is a field quantity and does depend on distance.  In other words, _"the sound power at 1 m distance"_ doesn't make sense.  Your question is a challenging one, actually, that is very specific to the audio system in question.  If it's a sealed enclosure system, this may be useful:  http://www.diysubwoofers.org/sld/sealed3.htm

Comment: @D.Betchkal I corrected the text.

Comment: This is a textbook case, widely used to demonstrate the sound radiation mechanisms. Usually it is defined as the baffled piston vibration. See e.g. Blackstock or Pierce Acoustics for details. The displacement amplitude (your "excursion") is used as the velocity amplitude (which is straightforward to transform in time-harmonic approach).